# Show the Inner product equals the Hermitian Product

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\langle., .\rangle$ denote the usual inner product in $\mathbb R^{2}$. In other words, if $Z = (x_{1}, y_{1})$
and $W = (x_{2}, y_{2})$, then
$\langle Z,W \rangle$ = $x_{1}x_{2} + y_{1}y_{2}$.
Similarly, we may define a Hermitian inner product $(·, ·)$ in $\mathbb C$ by
$(z, w)$ = $ \bar {zw}$.

The term Hermitian is used to describe the fact that $(·, ·)$ is not symmetric, but
rather satisfies the relation
$(z, w) = \overline{(w, z)}$ for all $z, w ∈ \mathbb C$.
Show that $\langle z, w \rangle = \frac{1}{2}[(z, w)+(w, z)] = Re(z, w)$, where we use the usual identification $z = x + iy ∈ C$ with $(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^{2}$.

What I have so far: 
$\langle z, w\rangle$=$x_{1}x_{2} + y_{1}y_{2}$

=$\frac{1}{2} (\overline {zw}+\overline {wz})$

Don't know what else to do.

Comment: A typesetting note, use \overline{} instead of \bar in order to get it to extend over everything $\overline{(w,z)}$ instead of $\bar{(w,z)}$, and use \langle \rangle instead of < >.  $\langle z,w\rangle$ keeps spacing more appropriate than $<z,w>$

Comment: Equal on which space?

Comment: This is the entire question. I found it from this book here: http://www.fing.edu.uy/~cerminar/Complex_Analysis.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember that for any complex number $z$, 
$$
Re(z)=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}
$$
Then 
$$
Re\left[ (z,w) \right] =Re\left[ z\overline{w} \right] =\frac{z\overline{w}+\overline{z\overline{w}}}{2} =\frac{z\overline{w}+\overline{z}w}{2}= \frac{1}{2}\left[ (z,w)+(w,z)\right]
$$
On the other side, by a direct computation
$$
Re\left[ (z,w) \right] = Re\left[ (x_1+iy_1)(x_2-iy_2) \right]=x_1x_2+y_1y_2 = \langle z,w \rangle
$$
Then, in fact $\langle z,w \rangle = Re\left[ (z,w) \right]=(1/2)\left[ (z,w)+(w,z)\right]$